# How do Russians translate "breaking news" caption on TV?

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

How do Russians translate "breaking news" caption on TV?

Comment: ломая новости )))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no expression with direct translation of "break" in sense of "make known suddenly".

Usually it's translated as *экстренные новости*, *экстренное сообщение*, *срочное сообщение* or *срочные новости*.

The title of the Hong Kong movie was translated as *Горячие новости* (literally "hot news").

Comment: It can also be "срочный выпуск новостей"

Comment: I think this was translated as "Экстренное сообщение"

Comment: @Karlson: this too.

Comment: I've also seen эксклюзи́вный репорта́ж somewhere. Or was it just эксклюзив ? link : http://english.sina.com/video/2012/0613/476287.html sorry for the video, but it's the only example I found.

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida эксклюзивный means that no other agency or channel has the same news. This may be not because it is 'breaking' but because they have signed a contract with a person or organization that performs the event (like "Formula 1 racing event in Monaco"), or because their correspondent was just in time at the place where something has happened.

Answer (score 5):

Сообщение ИТАР ТАСС с пометкой "Молния!"

Let me give some context:

You see, *ИТАР ТАСС* is one of Russian news agencies and *сообщение с пометкой "Молния!"* is a special kind of message that has to be delivered immediately. Its name comes from marks on urgent telegrams which were the closest approximation of old technologies to real-time communication. Since then, when "hot" news about an event is delivered to the TV studio during live broadcasting, the reporter may precede this message with words like *К нам поступило сообщение с пометкой "молния"*.

So, it's not strictly speaking a translation of "Breaking news", but it is still quite common on the TV.